# How to hide value help fields with annotation?

Tags: sapui5

I have the following value help dialog:

[image]

And would like to hide all fields except **Personal number** and **Full name**.

I would like to do it with annotation and tried as following:

[image]

But I could not find the `UI.hide` annotation like in CDS View, that is provided.

HINT: I am using OData model v2.

Answer (score 0):

OData.Core.V1.FieldControl annotation hide the fields of any entity in UI. Works fine with V2.

Example:

```
<Annotations xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Target="com.your.namesapce.<EntityName>/Personal number"><Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.FieldControl" EnumMember="Org.OData.Core.V1.FieldControlType/Hidden"/></Annotations>
```